# How to tell which pipe was written to first

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

So I have some code that I am working on where I'm going to fork N children to do something with N different files and gather some info. The parent is only reading, and the children are only writing. If one child finishes before the other, I'd like to start processing that data in the parent, while the others still run.

Here I am making N pipes

```
int pipefds[nFiles*2];
int k;
for(k = 0; k < nFiles; k++)
{
    if(pipe(pipefds[k*2]))
    {
     /* pipe failed */
    }
}
```

I then fork N processes, and want them to do something with the file and send it to the parent

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < nFiles; i++)
{
  pid = fork();
  if(pid < 0)
  {
    /* error */
  }
  else if(pid == 0)
  {
    /*child */

    close(pipefds[i*2]); //I think I want to close the Read End of each child's pipe
    getData(file[i]); // do something with the file this process is handling
    write(fd[i*2 +1], someData, sizeof(someData); // write something to the write end of the child's pipe
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
   /*parent*/
   if(i = nFiles -1) //do I have to make this condition so that I start once all processes have been started??
    {
      int j;
      for(j = 0; j < nFiles; j++)
      {
       close(pipefds[j*2+1]); //close all the parents write ends
      }
      /*Here I want to pick the pipe that finished writing first and do something with it */
    } 
  }
```

Do I have to wait for the last iteration of the for loop to start doing parent stuff (cause I want all the processes to start before I do anything)? Also How to I find the pipe in pipefds which is has finished writing so I can start handling it while the others run? Thanks!

Comment: C, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to create all the children first. Then run a separate loop around `poll` or `select`. When you get a read hit on one of the pipe ends, read the data into a buffer. If that read gets an indication that the other end of the pipe has closed, you can begin processing the data from that child. (Don't forget to remove that pipe from the set you are `poll`ing or `select`ing on.) When all children's pipes are closed, you're done.